# Python regex: Reject one two-digit number and accept other two-digit numbers

Tags: python, regex

How can I make a regular expression to not match a certain number with more than 2 digits. for example any number but 13. The second line of code below wont work it will not match 10, 11,... either and the third line will look for a number not starting with 1 but having a 3:

```
str = 'val=13'

regex = 'val=[^1][^3]'
regex = 'val=[^13]

re.search(regex, str)
```

Comment: Where does the data come from? If it is not being parsed from a file, avoiding regular expressions as others have pointed out might be a good idea.

Comment: Is the string a larger text with multiple `val=dd` values? Is the name of the variable always `"val"`? Can there be whitespace surrounding the equals sign? Will the number ever be negative?

Comment: do you also want to match numbers with 1 digit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** Changed to match numbers having one or more digits.

If you need to pluck out various forms of `val=dd` where dd must be a number having one or more digits, and that number cannot be 13 (or -13), and there may be whitespace surrounding the equals sign, and the number may have an optional leading +/- sign, then this script shows one way to do it:

```py
import re
# Regex: VERBOSE, commented version.
reLong = r"""
    # Match "val=dd" where dd has two or more digits (but is not 13).
    \bval\s*=\s*  # "val=" literal with optional ws.
    (?!           # Begin negative lookahead assertion.
      [+\-]?      # Number may have optional sign.
      13          # This is the number we don't match
      \b          # which ends on a word boundary.
    )             # The number is not 13, +13 or -13.
    (             # $1: Two digit number.
      [+\-]?      # Allow optional sign.
      \d+         # One or more digits.
    )             # End $1: containing 2 digit number
    """
# Regex: short, uncommented version.
reShort = r"\bval\s*=\s*(?![+\-]?13\b)([+\-]?\d{2}\b)"

# Compile a regex object we can use over and over.
reObj = re.compile(reLong, re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE)

# Test data strings. Positive and negative. With/without whitespace.
input = [
    # String with positive numbers. No whitespace.
    "val=1 val=13, val=133, val=12, otherval=1",
    # String with positive numbers. With whitespace.
    "val = 1 val = 13, val = 133, val = 12, otherval = 1",
    # String with negative numbers. No whitespace.
    "val=-1 val=-13, val=-133, val=-12, otherval=-1",
    # String with negative numbers. With whitespace.
    "val = -1 val = -13, val = -133, val = -12, otherval = -1",
    ]

# Parse all test data strings and print matches.
for str in input:
    matches = reObj.findall(str)
    if matches:
        print(matches)
```

The regex is presented in both short and long verbose form with comments. Here is the output from the script:

`['1', '133', '12']`
`['1', '133', '12']`
`['-1', '-133', '-12']`
`['-1', '-133', '-12']`

**Additional:**
To match something that is NOT something that is more than one character long, we use *negative lookahead*. For example, if one wants to match words which are NOT `"BAD"`, here is a commented regex which shows how:

```py
reobj = re.compile(r"""
    # Match a word that is not: 'BAD'
    \b         # Anchor to start of word.
    (?!BAD\b)  # Verify that this word is not 'BAD'
    \w+        # Ok. Safe to match non-BAD word.
    \b         # Anchor to end of word.
    """, re.VERBOSE)
```

Comment: It wont match val=1 or val=133

Comment: @Siavash M: Yes it does match `val=133` but no it doesn't match `val=1` because my understanding of the question is that you wanted to match only numbers having two or more digits. What is the number of digits you want to match? (Its easy to fix.)

Comment: The numbers can be anything - 1 to n digits. The question is how to do negative unmatch **larger than one character** long. We know that to match anything except "h" we could use `[^h]`, but what if we're looking for "hey" and "hi" but not "hello", `[^hello]` wont work

Answer (score 6):

Use lookahead assertions:

```
In : re.findall('val=(?!13$)(\d{2,})', 'val=12') 
Out: ['12']

In : re.findall('val=(?!13$)(\d{2,})', 'val=13') 
Out: []
```

Comment: Should be `(?13$)` otherwise `val=133` is blocked, too.

Comment: @Siavash M: it was not clear if you also wanted to match number with 1 digit. \d+ matches 1 or more, instead {2,} matches two or more.

Comment: @Vad, someone edited the question's title, so every things not clear now. Sorry

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need a regular expression?

```
>>> string = 'val=13'
>>> array=string.split("=")
>>> if array[0] == "val" and int(array[1]) < 100 and int(array[1]) == 13
...     print "match"
...
>>>
```

And all these are assuming I understood what you wrote.

Comment: you need `int()` around the numerical comparisons

Comment: in a small scale match like `val=13` this would work fine and is certainly lighter than a regex match. I just tried to simplify the question which lead to much debate :)

Answer (score 3):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 
>   “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”
>
> Now they have two problems.

Don't use regular expressions for stuff like this:

```
str = "val=13"
num = int(str.split("=")[1])

# a two-digit number ranges from 10 - 99
if 10 <= num <= 99 and num != 13:
    print("Success!")
```

Comment: generally, i'd agree, but in this special case, this is an easy to read one liner with a regex

Comment: Hm, you can formulate it the other way round: "Some people just don't get the regex syntax, so they try to avoid it in any case. Now they have importet a 20MB parsing library a 10MB lexing library and written 2000 lines of code. A small regex would have sufficed, but no, regex are evil!!!!!!11111". -1

Comment: nikic: Excuse me, the code I posted is 141 bytes (including comments), and doesn't use a 2000 line regex library. The small regex `'val=(?!13$)(\d{2,})'` suffices but my code beats it in terms of readability every time.

Comment: My question is a small part of a larger problem. I just tried to keep the question as simple as possible. The whole thing needs to be a RegEx

Answer (score 2):

If you really want a regex that matches two digits numbers except 13, then this should work:

```
>>> str = 'val=13'
>>> regex = 'val=(?!13$)(\d{2,})'
>>> re.search(regex,str)
>>> str = 'val=26'
>>> re.search(regex,str)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb75c0bf0>
```

However, as others pointed out, this may not be the best approach.

Comment: Good one. I would consider this question more of a theoretical one than of any practical usage. Your answer is proper.

Comment: @MarcoS, your answer doesn't match 10

Comment: @Mike Pennington: you're right! thank you for pointing this out. I corrected the code: negative lookahead assertions are required (see also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789740/python-regular-expression/5789939#5789939) )

Comment: to be more specific: that regular expresion does not match any number that either starts with a 1 or ends in a 3.

Comment: @MarcoS: he's asking to match a number with more than 2 digits, not just 2

Comment: @vad: I missed that part. So you do need `\d{2,}` in the regex. I fixed it. Also noticed the `$` to avoid blocking numbers like `133`!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a 'negative look ahead assertion':

```
p = re.compile("val=(?!13)[0-9]{2}")
assert not p.match('val=13')
assert p.match('val=23')
```